# How to assign a numeric variable in set_item command instead of a hard-coded value?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to bulk-edit a column in JavaScript with the same numerical value and have the following code that will work if I use a hard-coded number, but I want to use a variable from a user input instead:

```
function changeValues()
{
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListTitle");
var item;
for (item in selectedItems)
{
var newValue = document.getElementsByName("htmlInput")[0]; //This is the value I want to use 
var myResItem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
myResItem.set_item("ColumnName",newValue); //This is where hard-coded numbers work
myResItem.update();
}
```

I think I need to somehow format the "newValue" variable (SPFieldNumber?) but I have had no luck with my attempts thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are passing element.You have to pass value of this element.

```
myResItem.set_item("ColumnName",newValue.value);
```

And do not forget to insert below code after `myResItem.Update()`

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailed));
```

Also add following two methods

```
function onSuccess() {
    //alert message
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
   //alert message
}
```